# Pandas padding a DataFrame so it fills the bounds

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a function to pad a `DataFrame` that has a "datetime" index.

So, the idea is to add some "padding data" potentially before and/or after the dataframe so that it fits the given timeframe (`begin` and `end`).

The input dataframe has already been `resample`d previously. The `freq` parameter is the same as the sample frequency of the dataframe.

I'm open to any other solution that would be more "pandasic".

```py
def pad_dataframe(
    df: DataFrame,
    begin: datetime.datetime,
    end: datetime.datetime,
    *,
    columns: list[str],
    index: str,
    data: Callable[[datetime.datetime], Any],
    freq: datetime.timedelta,
):
    first = df.axes[0][0].to_pydatetime()
    last = df.axes[0][-1].to_pydatetime()

    to_concat = []
    if first > begin:
        pre_df = pd.DataFrame(
            columns=columns,
            data=[
                data(begin),
                data(first - datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)),
            ],
        ).set_index(index)
        # TODO: Fix
        # {TypeError}Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
        to_concat.append(pre_df.resample(freq).fillna(method="nearest"))

    to_concat.append(df)

    if last < end - freq:
        post_df = pd.DataFrame(
            columns=columns, data=[data(last + freq), data(end)]
        ).set_index(index)
        post_df.index = pd.to_datetime(post_df.index, utc=True)
        to_concat.append(post_df.resample(freq).fillna(method="nearest"))

    return pd.concat(to_concat)
```

and is used this way:

```py
begin = datetime.fromisoformat("2016-12-20 08:00:00+00:00")
end = datetime.fromisoformat("2016-12-20 10:07:00+00:00")
freq = timedelta(minutes=3)
df = some_other_function()

df = pad_dataframe(
                df,
                begin,
                end,
                columns=["timestamp", "count"],
                index="timestamp",
                data=lambda dt: [dt, 0],
                freq=freq,
            )
```

This is what I would expect:

```
         begin                    end
          |------------------------|

input             |----------------|
output    |ooooooo-----------------|

input     |----------------|
output    |-----------------ooooooo|

input             |-----------|
output    |ooooooo-------------oooo|

input     |------------------------|
output    |------------------------|
```

If the dataframe is out of the `begin-end` boundaries, I'm not sure what I would prefer: exception or no padding. Maybe an extra boolean `strict` parameter would be an acceptable solution.

Right now, my function has an issue at the resample moment, but maybe a totally \ different solution would make more sense in the `pandas` world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.
The idea was to create an "empty" DF with the desired Periods in the bounds. Then "merge" it with the input DF. A bit of cleanup after, it works.

```py
def get_frame_dataframe_between(
    begin: datetime.datetime, end: datetime.datetime, freq: datetime.timedelta
) -> DataFrame:
    min_accepted_freq = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    periods = (
        pd.period_range(begin, end, freq=min_accepted_freq)
        .to_frame()
        .resample(freq)
        .fillna(method="nearest")
        .drop(columns=[0])
    )
    return periods

def pad_dataframe(
    df: DataFrame,
    begin: datetime.datetime,
    end: datetime.datetime,
    *,
    fill_values: dict[str, Any],
    freq: datetime.timedelta,
) -> DataFrame:
    periods = get_frame_dataframe_between(begin, end, freq)

    out = pd.concat([df.to_period(), periods], axis=1)
    out.index.name = df.index.name
    out.fillna(value=fill_values, inplace=True)
    return out
```

And to use it:

```py
candle = pad_dataframe(
                df,
                begin,
                end,
                fill_values={"count": 0},
                freq=freq,
            )
```